# The upper bound on the size of special geometric graphs.

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, reference-request

Today, I went through an exercise in Bondy's textbook (Page 46, Exercise 2.1.24). I think the result is nice (seemingly non-obvious). However, I have not yet figured out how to prove it.

A *geometric graph* is a graph embedded in the plane in such a way that each edge is a line segment.

**Exercise** (H. Hopf And E. Panwitz) Let $G$ be a geometric graph in which any two edges intersect (possibly at an end-vertices).

a) Show that $G$ has at most $n$ edges.

b) For each $n \geq 3$, find an example of such a graph $G$ with $n$ edges.

For (b), I suspect that the authors constructed a cycle and found a straight-line drawing that satisfies the condition described above (any two edges intersect).

The authors  Hopf and Panwitz are mentioned in the book, but I'm not  sure which original reference proved it. I'd like to take a look at the proof. (Of course, it would be great if someone could prove it  as well.)

Comment: What is number $n$?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca It was lost in the original book, and I guess $n$
 is the number of vertices of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a geometric graph with $n$ vertices. We assume that any pair of edges intersect in at most $1$ point.

We can proceed by induction on $n$. If $G$ has any leaves, then we remove them and induct, so suppose otherwise. Suppose $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree at least $3$, and let $w_1, w_2, w_3$ be three of its neighbors, each of which has degree at least $2$. Since the other edge incident to $w_1$ must intersect both $v w_2$ and $v w_3$, we have that $w_2$ and $w_3$ are on the same side of the line $v w_1$. This holds for $w_2$ and $w_3$ in place of $w_1$ as well, but it clearly cannot hold for the `middle' $w_i$. Thus $G$ is 2-regular, so $G$ has $n$ edges.

We can go a bit further, showing that geometric graphs are even-cycle-free. This is because you have to keep bouncing back over the first segment you draw when drawing an even cycle, and the parity makes it so you end on the wrong side.

Constructions are relatively straightforward. Begin by drawing an odd-pointed star (or triangle). Then add pendant edges to the vertices extending across the star. This may be the only way to draw these geometric graphs.

Janos Pach in [https://users.renyi.hu/~pach/publications/beginnings020713.pdf](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Epach/publications/beginnings020713.pdf) seems to attribute this theorem to Erdos, who ``generously'' attributed the problem to Hopf and Panwitz.